# NPM, Supervisor, and Nohup exiting between shell sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm

I'm using Node LTS. I have a script that I need to keep always running. I need it to stay running even after I've disconnected from SSH. I also heard of a node package called [supervisor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor) that ensures a process restarts if it dies. My `package.json` has this:

`"start-continuous": "supervisor -t -i . index.js"`

Normally on Linux, when we want a program to stay running after logout, we do something like this:

`nohup ./programToRun > output.log 2>&1 &`

So, having the aforementioned `package.json`, I ran this:

`nohup npm run start-continuous > supervisor.out 2>&1 &`

Upon doing that, my node app began running in the background as I expected. However, when I disconnected from SSH and came back, it had exited. In the log I see:

```
Received SIGHUP, killing child process...
Parent process exiting, terminating child...
```

Can anyone with more node experience tell me either how I messed up with supervisor or the alternative you use to ensure your node scripts remain running forever?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. There was nothing wrong with what I was doing except that I had recently switched to the zsh shell. Apparently, zsh treats nohup or & differently. Why? Idk.

If this happens to you while using zsh, just run `bash` and then start your app with `nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PM2 Process management tools for always alive your NodeJS script.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2